# OpenSSH7.3p1 server is sending the protocol version with trailing space in Solaris?

Tags: erlang, solaris, openssh

I have experienced a strange issue with OpenSSH_7.3p1 (+OpenSSL 1.0.2k) and higher versions on Solaris 11 OS. When it acts as server, it is sending protocol version added with a trailing space and in case of client case without any space as shown below and is it acceptable

```
24 6.134324 192.168.0.5 192.168.10.2 SSHv2 90 Server: Protocol (SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.3 )
84 4.750896 192.168.0.5 192.168.10.9 SSHv2 89 Client: Protocol (SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.3)
```

Due to this while connecting from my client (Erlang) it is throwing the following error.

```
{error,{"Key exchange failed",{error,bad_signature}}}
```

Here my question is, as per [RFC4253 Protocol Version Exchange](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4253#section-4.2) it is mentioned as Space should be added only when the comments are specified. Am I right?

```
SSH-protoversion-softwareversion SP comments CR LF
```

Or Should I fix my client code to accept space?

/PRasad.

Comment: *it is mentioned as Space should be added only when the comments are specified.*  No, that's not what it says. The RFC states "If the 'comments' string is included, a 'space' character
   (denoted above as SP, ASCII 32) MUST separate the 'softwareversion'
   and 'comments' strings." The RFC doesn't specify whether the space is required, optional, or prohibited otherwise.  Since the space is listed as being part of the protocol version string, I can't see any reasonable interpretation of the RFC that makes the space wrong.  In fact, I'd say you could reasonably argue the space is *required*.

Comment: **Both the 'protoversion' and 'softwareversion' strings MUST consist of
   printable US-ASCII characters, _with the exception of whitespace
   characters_ and the minus sign (-).**   

    `SSH-2.0-billsSSH_3.6.3q3<CR><LF>`  

 
In another statement of RFC4253, Space is not allowed in protocol or software version strings.

Comment: That's just saying the protoversion and softwareversion can't have spaces or minus signs in them.  It doesn't refer to the trailing blank at all.  The exact quote from the RFC is:  *As such, **an example** of a valid identification string is  `SSH-2.0-billsSSH_3.6.3q3<CR><LF>`*  That example in no way precludes a space after the 'softwareversion' string and before the trailing <CR><LF>.  Does OpenSSH itself connect to the server?  If so, why do you think your interpretation of the RFC is better than the OpenSSH developers' interpretation?

Comment: **That's just saying the protoversion and softwareversion can't have spaces or minus signs in them. It doesn't refer to the trailing blank at all.** I couldn't agree with you. Why because RFC hasn't specified about any trailing space. But If I accept a string with space (anywhere) means It is allowed to have space char in it.  ***Does OpenSSH itself connect to the server?*** Yes, it is accepting a space char.

Comment: **why do you think your interpretation of the RFC is better than the OpenSSH developers' interpretation?** I have seen other clients which are failing due to same space. Why because the server is preparing a signature by considering the space in the software version string. Please don't mean it as arguing.